# How to get a name of the module from service, which process a request?

Tags: nestjs

I have a module with a controller and service.
I want to get a name of the module, which process a request.
Another situation: I have global module with a service, used in different modules.
How to get a name of the module, which process a request in global module?

I tried this, but it didn't work.

https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/execution-context

Comment: What's the use case here?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `@Inject(INQUIRER)`.

An example is here - https://github.com/nestjs/docs.nestjs.com/issues/937